# URLFOR Action to New Object for specific recordtype

Tags: visualforce, outputlink, urlfor

I have a custom object that has various record types. How would I construct URLFOR statement to take me to the new action for a particular record type?

URLFOR($Action.Relationship_Detail__c.New)

The RecordType I want to go to is called AccountAccountRelationship in the Record Type Name field

Also I feel like I should mention that this is part of an outputLink and the value is being set to this URLFOR

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need to use the p3 parameter for that.

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Relationship_Detail__c.New, null, [p3="Id of your record type",save=1])}
```

Please check the syntax though.

Comment: When I do that it goes to the new relationship page but it only prepopulates the dropdown box with the correct record type and then I have to push continue. Any way to skip the pushing continue and just go straight to the correct record type page?

Comment: try adding save=1, I edited my answer

Comment: No that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Sorry the save=1 actually saves the record. What id are you using for the p3 param? Is it the 15 digit or 18 digit number?

Comment: The 15 digit one

Comment: Where are you invoking this? In a button or VF page?

Comment: It is the value of an outputLink on a visualforce page